# Does Laravel calls json_decode once or more when querying JSONB column (cast to array)?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting), I can cast JSONB column as array with Laravel. It's great but I would like to understand how does it work under the hood. Because I don't know if it calls `json_decode` once or many time in this code (assuming `metadata` is a JSONB column):

```
echo $user->metadata['field_a'];
echo $user->metadata['field_b'];
echo $user->metadata['field_c'];
```

**Does Laravel calls json_decode once or three times?**

If so should I replace my code with this?

```
$meta = $user->metadata;
echo $meta['field_a'];
echo $meta['field_b'];
echo $meta['field_c'];
```

*Side note: It's not a question about micro-optimization. Sometimes I do multiple call to JSONB in big loops, so maybe I need to rewrite all.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel will do all casts once when the data comes from the database. All eloquent database functions will use the [`fill`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L219) function to set the properties of a model. And this function will set the attributes using the [`setAttribute`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L517) function.

The `setAttribute` function will check for casts and set the properties of the object accordingly. So the json is decoded once and then set as an object or array to the property.

Json strings are casted [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L535) in the `setAttribute` function.